# call an element inside json object with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i am trying to call an element inside a json object, here is a part of the code

```
{
    " academy": {
        "business": {
            "E-commerce": [
```

now i successed  to call `academy` as the first element, by this code

```
$.getJSON("professorUnversityCollegeCourseData.js", function(property) {
$.each(property, function (key, value) {
    $('#uni').add('<option value="'+ key + '" id="'+ count +'">'+ key +  
                  '</option>').appendTo('#university-selection');
    arrayUni[count] = key;
    count++;
});
```

how can i get the "business" element now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ever tried:

```
$.getJSON("professorUnversityCollegeCourseData.js", function(property) {
    $.each(property, function (key, value){
        $('#uni').add('<option value="'+ key + '" id="'+ count +'">'+ key + '</option>').appendTo('#university-selection');
        arrayUni[count] = key;
        count++;
        alert(this.academy.business);//Or also this['academy']['business']
    });
    alert(property.academy.business);//Or also property['academy']['business']
});
```

Comment: thanks , but i need to know the array number of business as i will complete my script depending on the `id= + count +` , so if the count number is `1` i will get the some colleges like business,engineering,science (1,2,3), i need to know the number of `business` and count on it to get all colleges under this academy

Comment: Yes, but business is an object, not an array. You can get the name of the property of business with this code: `for(var propName in property.business) alert(propName + ': ' + property.business[propName]);`

Comment: It's an object, it has no array number or length property, maybe it's not an object you are looking for, but an array ?

Comment: To treat it as an array you have to write your JSON by this way: `{
    " academy": {
        "business": [
            {
                name: "E-commerce"
            }`

Answer (score 1):

I think what you should do is this:

```
$.getJSON("professorUnversityCollegeCourseData.js", function(property){
    business = property.academy.business;
     //-or-
    business = property["academy"]["business"];
});
```

(according to the data you put up there.)

Comment: When calling `$.getJSON`, jQuery does the JSON parsing for you.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is what you are after

```
key.academy.business
```

It really is that simple, or :

```
key['academy']
```